# How to use Third Party tsp (Panasonic) with Tapi in Windows 7

Tags: telephony, tapi, pbx

I have installed a third party TSP, specifically Panasonic TSP version 4.0, and it's connected to the Panasonic PBX KX-TDE200.

I'm trying to connect my PBX with a TAPI application which will control the PBX's functionality, like call control and mainly class of service modification from the TAPI application itself.

This is where I got stuck.  As I am a newbie, I don't have much idea about telephony applications, so any help will be appreciated.

Comment: What is the question?  If you are just trying to get the application installed, you may have better luck at ServerFault or SuperUser.

Comment: @Mitch thanks for your reply.i want to write a simple tapi application which will communicate with Panasonic pbx using panasonic tsp...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For simplicity, you can use third party TAPI library such as

- [Teletools](http://www.exceletel.com/products/teletools.htm)
- [ATAPI](https://atapi.codeplex.com/)